# Wordpress. Contact Form 7. Не работают события

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form7

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7:mailsent', function( event ) {
  alert( "wpcf7mailsent!" );
}, false );

document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7:invalid ', function( event ) {
  alert( "wpcf7invalid !" );
}, false );

document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7:mailfailed  ', function( event ) {
  alert( "wpcf7mailfailed  !" );
}, false );

document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7:submit  ', function( event ) {
  alert( "submit  !" );
}, false );
```

Ни один из них не работает, как бы я не делал. Вписывал внутрь `$(document).ready(function () {` и без этого - без разницы.

При этом этот код работает:

```
$('.wpcf7-form').on('submit', function(){
  alert( "submit  !" );
} );
```

Не понимаю, чём причина? вроде всё правильно пишу.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7-form' );

wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  alert( "wpcf7mailsent!" );
}, false );

wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7invalid ', function( event ) {
  alert( "wpcf7invalid !" );
}, false );

wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailfailed', function( event ) {
  alert( "wpcf7mailfailed  !" );
}, false );

wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
  alert( "submit  !" );
}, false );
```

Полное описание событий https://contactform7.com/dom-events/

Comment: К сожалению, не сработало. Создал стандартную форму, ничего не менял - всё равно не работает ни один

Comment: Стандартные уведомления от CF7 работают исправно все. Никаких ошибок в консоли нет. Проверил код через w3c - всё ок

Comment: @РомаХр где-то можно посмотреть работу формы?